# Label into search button?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to have the label act as if it was a button and when you click on it, it searches what you put into the search box but have had no luck i use to have

```
<input type="submit" id='submit' value="search" >
```

but it looked ugly.. so is there anyway i could make the label act as that button i use to have?

the html:

```
<form action="/search.php" method="GET"> 
<input type="text" id="term" name="term">  
<label id="ca" for="search">Search</label>
</form>
```

the css:

```
div.search_bar input {
    background: transparent;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-clip: padding-box;

    border: none;

    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                        0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 
                        inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
                        0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                        0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 
                        inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
                        0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow:      inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                        0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 
                        inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
                        0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                        0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 
                        inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    color: #333;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0px 40px 0 40px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 35px 0 20px;

    transition:         all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition:    all .1s linear;
    -o-transition:      all .1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 3px;
}



div.search_bar label {
    background: transparent url(http://f.cl.ly/items/2a2Z0V0L0J1p3V082d3r/icon-search.png) no-repeat top left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
    left: 88%;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    top: -21px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Sure, you'll need to use Javascript to submit the form when you click on the label. jQuery fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCFp5/

Comment: Please don't use labels as a replacement for button or input...

Comment: To elaborate on @Bart's comment, if use a label in place of a submit button - anybody who has Javascript disabled or fails to load jQuery or is viewing it on a random system will not be able to submit your form. You are far better off using a submit button and styling it with CSS to look like a label so that if anything goes wrong, you still have a button.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work (warning - untested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ca').click(function() {
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
});
```

You'll also have to add an id to the form. `id="form1"`, and of course be using jQuery if you want to use this solution. But as mentioned in a comment above, using a label as a button is bad practice.

Comment: `using a label as a button is bad practice` - such a bad practice that I've never come across it in over 15 years :)

Answer (score 0):

Since some mini broswers like opera mini might not support JS, just remove the border from your submit button, keeping it all in html

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id='submit' value="search" >
```

CSS

```
#submit {border: none;}
```

Gives it a flat feel and obviously you can style the button any other way you want, but simply removing the border gives it a "label" feel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if your question is about look of it or the functionality. If it's the latter then since you're doing this such an unorthodox way, you can always get rid of the form

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="term" value="" />  
<label id="ca" for="term">Search</label>
```

**with jQuery**

```
$("#ca").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "/search.php?term="+$("#term").val();
});
```

---

**Without jQuery**

HTML `<label id="ca" for="term" onclick="doSearch();">Search</label>`

**Javascript:**

```
function doSearch(){
    var term = document.getElementById("term").value;
    window.location.href = "/search.php?term="+term;
}
```

Not recommended but I hope it helps what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `onClick` attribute in the Label like

```
<label id="ca" for="search" onClick="this.form.submit()">Search</label>
```